# How to install/enable ktpass.exe on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, kerberos

How can I install or enable the ktpass.exe utility on a Windows 7 workstation?

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately the answer is that keytabs for Kerberos cannot be generated on Windows 7. It must be generated using the ktpass utility on a Windows Server OS.

> The Keytab must be generated on either a member server or a domain
>   controller of the Active Directory domain using the ktpass.exe
>   command.  Use the Windows Server built-in utility ktpass.exe to create
>   the keytab.  The ktpass command must be run on either a member server
>   or a domain controller of the Active Directory domain.  Further,
>   Keytabs must be created on a Windows Server operating system such as
>   Windows Server 2008, 2012, or 2016.  **Keytabs cannot be created on a
>   workstation operating system, such as Windows 7, 8 or Windows 10**

- From the official Microsoft Docs.

Reference: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/36470.kerberos-keytabs-explained.aspx

EDIT: A potential workaround may be to install a linux vm and use `ktutil`

Comment: I've verified that using a linux (ubuntu in my case) WSL on Windows 10.  The packages seem to be "apt install krb5-config" "apt install krb5-user" (don't quote me, im not a linux guru).  You have to get the file "/etc/krb5.conf" (on the wsl) correct.  Running this ON WINDOWS gave me a magic value "gpresult /V" and then Find this: "Group Policy was applied from:"   I then had to ping the "applied from" value, and put that IP address in my krb5.conf. Here is a small example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53290348/how-to-setup-kerberos-realm-without-domain-name/53377633#53377633

Answer (score -2):

I believe this only applies To: Windows Server 2008, Windows Server 2008 R2, Windows Server 2012, Windows 8 according to Technet.